# Get Drawable from ImageView set from Camera app Android

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I am trying to capture an image from camera app and then use that pic as ImageView. Now I want to use that image as Drawable for uploading with following code

`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.images1);`

I want to get Image from R.id.imageView1 to be used in third paramater i.e. R.drawable.images1
because R.drawable would take images from drawable folder. Now how do I convert R.ID to DRAWABLE.

Please help!!

Comment: You could have used a `Drawable drw = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);`

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
//process image gotten from gallery
                if (requestCode == pick && resultCode == getApplicationContext().RESULT_OK) {

                    gpicture = true;

                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    final String location = data.getDataString();

                    Bitmap bitmap = null;

                    try {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

in the above code pic is your imageview and if you are confused about the request code == pic it is the variable you used when starting your activityonResult
hope this helps